# Windows-10 : Not able to access internet through Wi-Fi when Ethernet interface is not active

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, ethernet, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I have a windows-10 machine having 2 different interfaces.

**Ethernet adapter Ethernet:**

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

**Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:**

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1136:6e89:7bcf:dbfb%15

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.25

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.1

**Default route:**
[Click here to view the default route of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FywsO.png)

With these 2 interfaces running, when I try to ping any website using wifi interface (ping xxx.com -S 192.168.42.25) from windows power shell, it's able to ping successfully. But as soon as I remove ethernet and allow only wifi interface on the machine, and try to ping the same way, then machine is not able to get the connectivity from the remote router through this wifi interface.

I'm not able to understand what can be the cause. Is there anything that ethernet is resolving internally and providing the connectivity through wifi? As in absence of it I'm not able to access the internet at all. I would be thankful if you can provide some keywords I need to know or any reference or links for the mentioned issue. That will really help.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, is the ping command using IPv4 or IPv6 ? Try pinging with the -4 option. Secondly, could you run the command 'route -4 print' and add the output to your opening post ? This might be helpful in determening the issue.

Comment: Your wireless is on a different subnet than your wired connection. You likely have a wireless router that is connected so that it is not on your main network.

Comment: Hii @Silbee, ping is using IPv4 and I've attached the default route screen shot as per your suggestion. Also I had tried pinging with -4 option which couldn't solve the issue. Thank you for looking into this problem.

Comment: Hii @John, Thank you for taking the interest. Yes, your observations are right. I request you if you can reach to the route cause of the problem or even share your thoughts on the same.

Comment: If your wireless router is different to the main router, then connect it as follows:  LAN port on wireless to LAN port on network, Static IP on wireless, turn DHCP OFF on wireless.  This is the mos likely cause and solution. If wireless is included in the main router (that is, one router) then turn wireless isolation OFF on the main router. This is also possible.

Comment: You have 2 routers and 2 networks, which unless you you did this purposefully, is just going to give you headaches. I assume you your WiFi router is connected to the router you also connect your ethernet adapter to. On the WiFi router, turn off its routing capabilities and use it as an access point instead. Make sure it gets an IP address by DHCP or set it staticly like ip192.168.0.10 mask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.1